# Error websocket con catapult y typescript / angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http, websocket

estoy recibiendo error de 404, estoy intentando conectarme a un Webservice en Typescript, el webservice es de catapult, al abrir la conexión la salida es http y no ws, aun cuando en mi parámetro de url coloco ws://mi-ip.

```
import { Listener, BlockInfo } from "nem2-sdk/dist";
const listener = new Listener('ws://miIp:3000');
listener.open();
```

Al hacer lo que hice arriba, la salida en el navegador es la siguiente:

```
GET http://miIp:3000/ws 404 (Not Found)

Fetch API cannot load http://miIp:3000/ws. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

¡¡ AYUDA POR FAVOR !!

Este es el ejemplo que yo estoy haciendo
https://nemtech.github.io/guides/blockchain/listening-new-blocks.html

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco como funciona catapult, pero este error siempre se da cuando en el Servidor no están bien controlados los origenes de acceso.

Si estas consumiendo un servicio de la nube, debe de haber una sección donde se configuran los origenes permitidos de javascript.

Si estas utilizando un servidor propio, necesitas investigar como configurar el CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing), si tienes dudas con esto puedes hacer otra pregunta especifica para el lenguaje y servidor que estas utilizando.